# Windows Phone 8 and LAN communication Client-Server-Client

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to make Client(WP8 device) -> Server(Windows 8 Desktop device) -> Client(WP8 device) connection. By this conn I wanna send data from one phone to another phone. What should I use? TcpClient in Net.Sockets is not supported by WP 8 as well as UdpClient.

Comment: Ok no answers so I decided to make client using HTML5 websockets and server using C# .NET websockets

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at this [Communications for windows phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637518%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

And maybe this might help as well [How to create and use a TCP socket client app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, your first link is useful :)